# How to introduce % in SQL consult in java

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to set a sql query like this:

```
SELECT id 
FROM example_table
WHERE agent not like '%example'
```

I tried that in SQL Developer and works fine, but in Java I don`t get what I want to:

```
String= "%example"
(...)
query=""
+ "SELECT id"
+ "FROM example_table"
+ "WHERE agent not like ?"
(...)
pst.setString(n++, String);
(...)
```

I don't get any error but the query doesn't give the result I want, I think the point is that setting the String is not compatible with "%".

Thank you in advance

EDIT:
 SOLUTION:

```
String= "example"
    (...)
    query=""
    + "SELECT id"
    + "FROM example_table"
    + "WHERE agent not like **concat('%', ?)"**
    (...)
    pst.setString(n++, String);
    (...)
```

That simple :)

Comment: May I ask why you are using placeholder in your query string?

Comment: Yeah, I want to have the chance to change it whenever I want.